# What manner of reverse voltage protection circuit should I add to this schematic?

Tags: schematics, circuit-protection, reverse-polarity

This is a continuation from [my previous post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/638350/what-are-the-major-flaws-of-this-pcb-atmega328-design) where I asked for feedback about my designs. There was a lot to say about them. In trying to follow all of the advice I was given, and applying all the changes suggested, I find myself stuck on how I should go about protecting the circuit from reverse polarization resulting from connecting the VCC and GND wires in each other's place.

These are the *slightly* updated schematics regarding my previous question:

[image]

The PCB design:

[image]

I spent most of this morning making minor changes, but this is where I have to stop and ask for (even more) advice. You see, I was told that I should add protection to the circuit, and I was also told that a small fuse and a 1N4004 diode can be enough to get the job done. I started reading about reverse voltage protection, and how there are a few ways to go about it, one of them including the usage of a PMOS MOSFET with a resistor and a Zener diode like in the following schematic:

[image]

I want to go about this efficiently  unless I risk compromising the integrity of the circuit as a whole, which is why I would like to hear your thoughts about your recommended way to protect this particular electrical circuit.

I still have to put all the other suggestions into effect, and I intend to, provided I can adapt the schematic and the PCB design to meet all of the required criteria. Until then, I am once again asking for your knowledge and advice.

Comment: Before getting to reverse protection, do note that all of your push buttons are shorted.  If you choose to use the internal pull-ups on the I/O lines you do not need to connect the button circuits to Vcc.

Comment: Also, the zener diode you show for the protection circuit is 6.8Vz, the data sheet for ATMEGA328 lists the absolute max operating voltage at 6.0V.  So if you wanted to use such a circuit a zener such as 1N4626 (5.6Vz  5%) would be a better choice.

Comment: Another improvement to your PCB would be to move R9 & R10 near the bottom center of the board.  You could then reduce the board size and the routing of the traces could be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

One of the more simple forms of reverse protection is just a single general purpose diode placed in reverse bias on your supply inputs. The extra circuitry you show is good but may be a bit more then is needed, (it actually prevents a reverse connection from getting to the circuitry and adds over voltage protection). For simple reverse supply protection you also need to know what the external supply is capable of. If the supply itself is fused adequately then the single diode on the board may be enough. If the supply is not fused you might consider placing a fuse on your board. Keep in mind that you should also consider the chances of a reverse condition. If the power connections are to be directly wired between the board and supply there is little chance of a user later disconnecting and reconnecting the wires in reverse. If the connections are being made with a non-polarized connector that is easily disconnected and reconnected then the possibility of a reverse connection is a greater concern.

As for a few final tips:
For a through hole component you usually do not need an extra via to contact a bottom layer ground plane, (your layout software should create typical thermal connecting pads on the bottom layer, in case it doesn't then a short bottom layer trace could be used, enable the bottom layer view to be sure there is a connection, alternately allow your software to do a design check to verify all connections).

Where practical use diagonal traces to simplify and reduce trace lengths, (as you see using only 90 degree traces sometimes requires odd zigzag patterns).

Keep traces to decoupling caps as short as possible, (extra trace length and sharp angles can reduce their effectiveness).

If you want to have a well documented PCB consider adding text on a silk screen layer with font sizes large enough to be easily read (and above the PCB vendor's minimum size).  If you don't want the expense of an extra silk screen layer your board has plenty of space to add text using the top copper layer.

Don't forget to consider how the PCB will be mounted, mounting holes are easy for a PCB vendor to add.

[ Additional edits made. ]

Answer (score 1):

For reverse protection, you can connect your supply through a resettable fuse ('polyfuse') and connect a power diode across the fused supply rail.

Connect the diode anode to the 0 V rail and the cathode to the fused positive rail.

An accidental reversal of the supply will be clamped to -0.8..-1.1 V or so by the power diode and then the resettable fuse can cut the supply off.

When the reverse supply is disconnected, the fuse will soon reset itself.

This uses fewer components than the MOSFET circuit you considered.

[image]